# When i click on modal then show duplicate URL

Tags: jquery, angular, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I have Bootstrap modal for insert data when i click on an add  button  console of chrome is showing  error message saying like the below image, i solved the problem by separating the add button component and bootstrap modal component but when i click the button the url is changing[image]

button open modal:

```
  <button class="btnAddPackage rainbow-text" data-toggle="modal" id="myBtn" 2 
  data-target="#exampleModal" 
  data-whatever="@mdo">
  <i class="fa fa-plus"></i> New Package</button>
```

Html modal:

```
   <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" 
   aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" 
    data-backdrop="false"  aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" id="close-modal" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"  
        aria-hidden="true">X</button>
        <p class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Add Package</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <form (ngSubmit)="create()">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="recipient-name" [(ngModel)]="formTest.name" name="name" placeholder="Packag Name">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="recipient-name" [(ngModel)]="formTest.price" name="price"  placeholder="Price">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="recipient-name" [(ngModel)]="formTest.count" name="count" placeholder="Points">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="recipient-name" [(ngModel)]="formTest.createAt" name="createAt" placeholder="Number Of Month">
          </div>
          <button  role="button" class="btnAddPackage2" onclick="hideModal()">Add</button>
     </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Script:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#myBtn").click(function(){
$("#exampleModal").modal("show");
});
$('#close-modal').modal('hide');
});
</script>
```

Routering:

```
   {
    path:'package',
    component: PackageComponent
   }
```

Comment: can  u provide the code of  `routerLink`.  you are `routing` to a path `package/package` which is not there.

Comment: no i provide just  { path:'package', component: PackageComponent  }

Comment: I cant see any routing in the provided code

Comment: i added it above

Comment: don't write jQuery in Angular... use a package like ng-bootstrap or Angular-material if you want to use modals... Thanks

Comment: Thanks for reply, but what different if i don't use jQuery here !!? Akber Iqbal

Comment: @MohamadAlhamid where is `[routerLink]]` in html or `this.router.navigate` in `ts` file ? `{
    path:'package',
    component: PackageComponent
   }` has nothing to do with error. The error is coming because you are providing wrong path for navigation. I hope you are getting my point

Comment: i was removed this.router.navigate, but nothing change

Comment: the parent component is package, why show package/package i don't know

Comment: I find solution but not good approach, i add this in the routing file:                      
                {
                  path:'package/package',
                  redirectTo:'/package'
                 }